# How to count number of nodes per depth in a breadth_first search in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to design an MLM application. It operates like Person A sponsors 3 persons and B, C, D and each of B, C, and D sponsors 3 more and so on.

To calculate the payouts, client wants the graph to be traversed based on the last person of the 3, say D and total payout is based on the number of people under D multiplied by a specific amount. Now the challenge for me is a constraint whereby for each level, you only need to count n-1 persons where n maxes out at 3 as that is the MLM strategy.

I am using embedded Neo4j for the project so far I know i can traverse based on the relationship and perhaps do a bread_first search and get the current depth but how do I count the number of persons minus 1 for each level in the traversal? It seems, I may have to implement a custom method but I need help to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as long as you know what depth you're at, you can use the depth as an index into a collection (an array for example).  Every time you visit a node at a given depth, increment the value at that index in the collection.

Once you're finished your traversal, you can apply what ever rules and constraints you like to the array of data.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. I will give the approach a try and feedback with results... However, I am not quite sure how to populate the array of list with the leaf nodes.. Would I just initialize the list and add the traversal at each index to my list?